# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Utilizo android studio 2.3.3

y cada vez que inicio un nuevo proyecto me marca este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi archivo granddle Module:App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yahlopee.capteurs"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.186'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

y este es el build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

ya he intentado agregar en allprojects maven, pero ni aun asi funciona, alguien tiene alguna solucion y tampoco puedo cliquear el enlace que parece debajo del error

Comment: De preferencia que el codigo y el log sea texto es mas facil para hacer pruebas

Comment: excelente, lo hago

Comment: acabo de agregar el mavenCentral para ver si funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas definiendo:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

y

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

pero estas usando Android Studio 2.3.3, [el máximo soporte para esta versión es para API level 26](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-1-0), si es que funcionara con Android Studio 2.3.3 incluso implicaría cambiar la versión de Gradle de:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

a:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Te recomiendo actualices a android 3.0.1 que es la versión estable (Marzo 2018), de esta forma podrás usar la API 27 sin problema :

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando el repositorio de google

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Es recomendable que no utilices el comodin `.+`, ya que puede que una actualizacion del modulo, deje de ser compatible con tu proyecto. Para el caso del `appcompat-v7`, el import mas actual es `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'`